# Make UserControl "slide out" from a side of a screen?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I'm using following code to inject view into Grid:

```
private void OnShowNotesRequested(UserControl view)
        {
            if (view == null) throw new NotSupportedException("View should not be null");

            // Skip first GridRow - this is usually Toolbar
            if (this.AssociatedObject.RowDefinitions.Count > 1)
            {
                view.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, this.AssociatedObject.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
                view.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
            }

            view.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, this.AssociatedObject.ColumnDefinitions.Count == 0 ? 1 : this.AssociatedObject.ColumnDefinitions.Count);
            view.Width = 500;
            view.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;

            this.AssociatedObject.Children.Add(view);
        }
```

Basically, I'm adding view as a child to the Grid. It docks to the right side.

I want to make it look like this view sliding out of right side and stops. I have no idea on how to approach it and what should I do to achieve this visual effect. Any pointers on what and where I need to add? Maybe link to similar effect?

I found some animations code here: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/82441.aspx

It makes sense, however when I hide my view - I completely remove it from visual tree like so: `this.AssociatedObject.Children.Remove(view)` Not sure how to "wait" and then remove it.

Comment: I recommend Expression Blend.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Microsofts Expression Blend tool, its been created specifically to create these kind of visual effects.

What you are looking to do can be acheived with a story board and is pretty simple to do!

Essentially, once the storyboard has been created (a case of defining the starting position and the end position - according to time (or frames)) you can trigger the storyboard to play when a particular event is fired.

I know this is not a definitive answer however here are some tutorials to get you moving:

http://www.silverlightbuzz.com/2009/10/12/animating-with-storyboards-in-blend/
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mamta_m/creating-and-using-storyboards-in-blendsilverlight-part-i/
http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CE4QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fcc295092.aspx&ei=NDRzT42uPNS_8gPrz6xW&usg=AFQjCNGwT_hEkwGBXzS3holaM1g85I0S5Q&sig2=dSDJ6lL0CR3-nIR7WQ739g

Thanks and good luck!

Ben